# SSH service running on multiple ports with custom rules in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, centos

I was working on setting up a server with SSH service running on multiple ports like say, port 22, and 5522 and these port should be having a different set of rules, ie: The rules we added for port 22 should not conflict with the rules for port 5522.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, the SSH service can be made to listen to multiple ports by adding the following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
Port 22
Port 5522
```

In this scenario, you cannot define different rules for different ports.

One of the solutions I could find is to create a new service to run SSH service on port 5522 and then running the service as daemon.

To do so please follow steps below:-

1. create a copy of the SSH service and name it, here I named the copy as `sshd_config_custom`

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom
```

2. Similarly, create a copy of the service too.

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service /lib/systemd/system/sshd-custom.service
```

3. open `/lib/systemd/system/sshd-custom.service` using any comfortable editor and change

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom
```

And

```
Alias=sshd.service
```

to

```
Alias=sshd-custom.service
```

Save and exit the file.

4. Now you can add the line `Port 5522` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_custom` and can make any required changes to this conf file.
5. Enable and start the custom service that we have created.

```
systemctl enable sshd-custom.service
systemctl start sshd-custom.service
```

Let me know if there is any other suggestions