# Setup git SSH server without opening up the management users

Tags: git, ubuntu, security, ssh, gitlab

Currently I'm in the process of setting up a Gitlab server.
What would be a good way to expose the ssh endpoint to the internet (as this is the default git protocol) and still allowing ssh for managing the server.

Allowing managment (password protected) users to authenticate from the internet does not seem very "secure".

Can I restrict a certain user (git) to only connect from a specific IP adress as a firewall + reverse proxy would be in place.

Thanks for any info you guys can share!

Comment: How about this https://techietown.info/2017/05/restrict-ssh-access-for-users-from-specific-ip-address/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to do that for my shop:

1. SSH port 22 is never (in a big company environment) opened to internet, or even open to enterprise load-balancer/reverse-proxy redirecting traffic: it is not an allowed public ingress point, in my experience
2. A dedicated SSH port, with its own SSH daemon should be defined on that GitLab server, with:

   - only one dedicated account allowed ([`AllowUsers`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-limit-what-users-can-log-onto-system-via-ssh/))
   - no interactive session possible ([`PasswordAuthentication no`](https://askubuntu.com/q/72902/5470))
   - only a forced command used in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`, calling `gitlab_shell`
3. A load-balancer/reverse-proxy (typically [F5 in big company](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/glossary/load-balancer), as [reverse-proxy](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy)) would redirect a public 22 port from a DMZ to the private dedicated SSH port on your server

Comment: Thanks for the update this got me pointed in the correct direction.
Using the pointers you gave I found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443935/ssh-service-running-on-multiple-ports-with-custom-rules-in-linux. 
I then found a hardend sshd file over here:  https://github.com/k4yt3x/sshd_config/blob/master/sshd_config

Comment: @TomDierckx Good catch. That should work indeed.